# file ctime different under perl 5 and perl 6

Tags: raku

OS: Windows Server 2012 R2 Standart
FS: NTFS

=== perl5

```
e:\temporary>perl -v
This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 0 (v5.22.0) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

e:\temporary>type ctime.pl
use File::stat;
use Time::Piece;

my $fn1 = 't:\temporary\tia\Энергия\print.pdf';
my $fn2 = 't:\temporary\tia\Энергия\kl_to_1c.txt';
for ($fn1,$fn2) {
    my $fs = stat($_);
    print "$_\n";
    print 'changed  ',gmtime($fs->ctime)->datetime,"\n";
    print 'modified ',gmtime($fs->mtime)->datetime,"\n";
    print 'accessed ',gmtime($fs->atime)->datetime,"\n";
}

e:\temporary>perl ctime.pl
t:\temporary\tia\Энергия\print.pdf
changed  2016-07-01T03:48:22 <== (1)
modified 2016-05-04T03:03:08
accessed 2016-07-01T03:48:22
t:\temporary\tia\Энергия\kl_to_1c.txt
changed  2016-07-01T03:48:22 <== (3)
modified 2016-07-01T03:11:00
accessed 2016-07-01T03:48:22
```

=== perl6

```
e:\temporary>perl6 -v
This is Rakudo version 2016.04 built on MoarVM version 2016.04
implementing Perl 6.c.

e:\temporary>type ctime.pl6
use v6;
my $fio1 = 't:\temporary\tia\Энергия\print.pdf'.IO;
my $fio2 = 't:\temporary\tia\Энергия\kl_to_1c.txt'.IO;

for $fio1,$fio2 {
    say .path;
    say 'changed  ', .changed.DateTime.truncated-to('second');
    say 'modified ', .modified.DateTime.truncated-to('second');
    say 'accessed ', .accessed.DateTime.truncated-to('second');

}

e:\temporary>perl6 ctime.pl6
t:\temporary\tia\Энергия\print.pdf
changed  2016-05-04T03:03:08Z <== (2)
modified 2016-05-04T03:03:08Z
accessed 2016-07-01T03:48:22Z
t:\temporary\tia\Энергия\kl_to_1c.txt
changed  2016-07-01T05:46:12Z <== (4)
modified 2016-07-01T03:11:00Z
accessed 2016-07-01T03:48:22Z
```

Why (1),(2) and (3),(4) are different?
It's OK?

Reproducing (1),(2).
1) Create file with text editor. Difference will be in seconds.
From perl5:

```
 changed  2016-06-30T16:38:42
 modified 2016-06-30T16:38:48
 accessed 2016-06-30T16:38:42
```

From perl6:

```
 changed  2016-06-30T16:38:48Z
 modified 2016-06-30T16:38:48Z
 accessed 2016-06-30T16:38:42Z
```

2) Edit this file several minutes later.  Difference will be more noticeable.
From perl5:

```
  changed  2016-06-30T16:38:42 <==
  modified 2016-06-30T16:49:17
  accessed 2016-06-30T16:38:42
```

From perl6:

```
 changed  2016-06-30T16:49:17Z <==
 modified 2016-06-30T16:49:17Z
 accessed 2016-06-30T16:38:42Z
```

'stat' from cgwin/babun:

```
{ ~ }  » stat t:/temporary/tia/Энергия/print.pdf                                                ~
  File: ‘t:/temporary/tia/Энергия/print.pdf’
  Size: 81595           Blocks: 80         IO Block: 65536  regular file
Device: dfe235h/14672437d       Inode: 26458647810801926  Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  500/Administrator)   Gid: (  513/Domain Users)
Access: 2016-07-01 09:48:22.578784100 +0600
Modify: 2016-05-04 09:03:08.602697600 +0600
Change: 2016-05-04 09:03:08.602697600 +0600
 Birth: 2016-07-01 09:48:22.578784100 +0600

{ ~ }  » stat t:/temporary/tia/Энергия/kl_to_1c.txt                                           ~ 1
  File: ‘t:/temporary/tia/Энергия/kl_to_1c.txt’
  Size: 4596            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 65536  regular file
Device: dfe235h/14672437d       Inode: 24769797950537989  Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  500/Administrator)   Gid: (  513/Domain Users)
Access: 2016-07-01 09:48:22.563158800 +0600
Modify: 2016-07-01 09:11:00.585249200 +0600
Change: 2016-07-01 11:46:12.037712200 +0600
 Birth: 2016-07-01 09:48:22.563158800 +0600
```

Comment: What is the result of just calling the `stat` command on the file?

Comment: I updated the example using UTC/GMT. Since Windows does not have 'stat' got the data with cgwin/babun shell

Comment: The docs for [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html "perldoc -f stat") mention that `ctime` is not portable. Looking at the [`stat` section of perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#stat) it mentions that `ctime` is creation time on Windows. It is possible that Rakudo does something different to attempt to be more portable. ( It could also be a bug )

Answer (score 3):

This may be a bug originating in libuv (see: https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2016-07-11#i_12818620). Even if it is, it should not drop through into Perl 6 code. Please file a bug report against Rakudo (see: http://rakudo.org/tickets/).

Comment: Huh.. I was sure perl6 was the one returning the correct values? It seems to return distinct times for `Энергия\kl_to_1c.txt`, not to mention it seems to agree with cygwin's stat output.. Maybe I'm mistaken?

Comment: @Timbus There is no wrong or right in this matter. It's a question of personal preference how to map those 4 timestamps on the 3 posix ones. In cases where there is no good reason to change the behaviour between Perl 5 and Perl 6 we want to stay as close to Perl 5 as possible to make it easier to port from 5 to 6 and to avoid traps when using Inline::Perl5.

Also the correct way in Perl 5 would be to use Win32API::File::Time. The same is true for Perl 6 and you are very welcome to write that module. :)